# Why does my float type-casting expression return two different values?

Tags: java, casting, expression

Here are the expressions I'm working with:

```java
float firstValue = (float) (5 / 2); //output is 2.0
float secondValue = (float) 5 / 2; //output is 2.5
```

I'm stumped here and can't figure out why this type casting is returning two different values. I understand I can just do `(5f / 2f)` but I wanted to experiment using the other type casting with an expression. Why is `firstValue` 2.0 and `secondValue` 2.5? Where did the .5 go?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Comment: In the first example you are casting (int) 2 to (float) 2.0

Comment: In Java, the default integer type is `int`. So, in the expression `(5 / 2)`, you're perhaps unwittingly invoking integer division, so 5 divided by 2 is  2 with a remainder of 1, but you're not asking for the remainder so it's just ignored.

Comment: @timmyen following the community practice.. do TICK mark the answer/answers , you found correct n helpful. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is integer math. This

```
float firstValue = (float) (5 / 2);
```

First divides five by two and gets two. Then it converts two to `2.0`. The second is floating point math.

```
float secondValue = 5f / 2;
```

Which is 2.5 (and a `float`). Because a `float` divided by an `int` is a `float`.

Comment: How come this concept does not apply to multiplication? For example, (float)(5 * 2.5) results in 12.5? The value of (5*2.5) does not get truncated to 12.0?

Comment: @timmyen (float)(5 * 2.5)  --> (float)(5 * 2.5f) --> (float)(12.5f) --> 12.5f

Comment: @timmyen Now.. if you do (int)(5 * 2.5) --> (int)(5 * 2.5f) --> (int)(12.5f) --> 12  [So the final answer here loses precision, as it gets  casted to int]

Answer (score 4):

As brackets have the highest precedence, they get solved first

```
float firstValue  = (float) (5 / 2);  // division of integers
                  = (float) (2);      // 5/2 = 2 , as Integers are being divided
                  = 2f
float secondValue = (float) 5 / 2; // division of float with integer
                  = ((float) 5) / 2;
                  = 5f / 2;          // second value is equivalent to this
                  = 2.5f             // as Float divided by Integer is Float
```

Answer (score 2):

1. float firstValue  = (float) (5 / 2);  // division of integers

The first step is to do 5/2 calculation.Then the answer is given in float.If you explain further 5 and 2 are int numbers. After calculating the int for two int numbers, the final answer is returned by int. Here the final int answer (2) is converted to a float answer. That is, wider conversion is used here. So the final answer is the integer value(2) shown in float form(2.0).

2.float secondValue = (float) 5 / 2; //output is 2.5
Since the first value(5) is named a float number, the final answer is the decimal itself